# How to give age validation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Have created below function for age validation, but its not giving me proper out. Anyone know how to do it ?

Some other code tried but it was depricated. My app target is iOS 7 and later.

> Selected Date - 13/03/1990 Output
>
> You live since -68 years and -35 days

```
-(BOOL)validateAge
{
    NSString *birthDate = _txtBirthDate.text;
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    int time = [todayDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:birthDate]];
    int allDays = (((time/60)/60)/24);
    int days = allDays%365;
    int years = (allDays-days)/365;

    NSLog(@"You live since %i years and %i days",years,days);

    if(years>=18)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't taking leap years into account

Comment: Is your _txtBirthDate.text comes in "yyyy-MM-dd" format?

Comment: maybe your `dateFormatter` and `birthDate ` are in different format, u have to put it same format (like 1990/01/01 and yyyy/MM/dd), else your code work fine for me, it out put 25 years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks perfect to me!

Problem seems to me is with your _txtBirthDate.text format. It should be in yyyy-MM-dd

I run your code with static string value in place of _txtBirthDate.text and got perfect result. Check below code for your reference.

```
NSString *birthDate = @"1990/03/15";
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
int time = [todayDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:birthDate]];

int allDays = (((time/60)/60)/24);
int days = allDays%365;
int years = (allDays-days)/365;

NSLog(@"You live since %i years and %i days",years,days);
```

Output:

```
- You live since 25 years and 280 days
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSCalendar` API to get the number of date components between particular dates.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:birthDate toDay:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSLog(@"You live since %i years and %i days", components.year, components.day);
```

You can't rely on the assumption that year has 365 days(consider leap years). Also, the day duration is not always 24 hours(consider DST changes). It could bring errors in your calculations. `NSCalendar` handles all this stuff correctly.